# Loop and merge/update data

Tags: python, pandas, merge, group-by

I have two data frames which look like:

```
DF1:

x_id     y_id 
 1       NaN
 2       NaN
 3       NaN 
 4       NaN
 5       NaN
 6       NaN 


DF2:

x_id     y_id 
 1       1
 2       1
 3       1 
 4       2
 5       2
 6       2
 1       3
 3       3 
 :       :
 :       :
 3       y(i)
```

So, I want to merge/insert y_id from DF2 into y_id in DF1 in each iteration of the loop.

What I have so far:

```
count = df2['y_id'].unique()
for i in count: 
    new_df = df1.merge(df2['y_id']==i], how='inner', left_on='x_id', right_on='x_id')
```

While this create a new dataframe for each iteration of the loop, I think there should be a better way of doing this.

I want my final data frame to look like:

```
DF3:

x_id     y_id 
 1       3
 2       1
 3       y(i) 
 4       2
 5       2
 6       2
```

Essentially what I want to do is group DF2 by y_id and merge them in a sorted order. So we can see in DF2 the values 1 and 3 have y_id = 1 and then further down the column they have y_id = 3. Since three is >1 I would like to use this value (ie. the greatest or most recent if we were working with dates etc.)

What I want to do is similar to an update statement in SQL where we update the column and set the row = y_id, taking the most recent value.

Hope I have explained sufficiently, any questions just ask.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can `drop_duplicates` before `merge`

```
df1=df1.drop('y_id',1).merge(df2.drop_duplicates('x_id',keep='last'),on='x_id')
df1
Out[469]: 
   x_id  y_id
0     1     3
1     2     1
2     3     3
3     4     2
4     5     2
5     6     2
```

Comment: Ok my example should have been better. My y_id column will be constantly updating, I cannot choose which value to drop.